# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php

i need help on this errer please i intall this script  on my easyphp what wrong ?

```
Warning: require_once(C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb\studentTrans\includes\config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\StudentTranscript Processing System in PHP with MySQL\includes\initialize.php on line 21
```

hello  , i need help on this errer please i intall this script  on my easyphp what wrong ?

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/data/localweb\studentTrans\includes\config.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\StudentTranscript Processing System in PHP with MySQL\includes\initialize.php on line 21



 //define the core paths
 /Define them as absolute peths to make sure that require_once works as 
 expected

 //DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP Pre-defined constants:
 //(\ for windows, / for Unix)
 defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

 defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define ('SITE_ROOT', 
 $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DS.'studentTrans');

 defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define ('LIB_PATH',SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

 // load config file first 
   require_once "config.php";
//load basic functions next so that everything after can use them
  require_once "functions.php";
  //later here where we are going to put our class session
  require_once "session.php";
  require_once "member.php";
  require_once "student.php";
  require_once "student_details.php";
  require_once "student_requirements.php";
  require_once "department.php";
  require_once "sy.php";
  require_once "instructor.php";
  require_once "instructorclasses.php";
  require_once "studSubjects.php";
  require_once "grades.php";
  require_once "room.php";

//Load Core objects
require_once"database.php";

//load database-related classes
```

Comment: On windows, correct way of slashes is this \  So it's your path wrong. Normal to get an error.

Comment: hi so what i have to change ? thx

Comment: where is the code you include initialize.php

Comment: look in code this is file initialize.php  start from   defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

Comment: I would assume that you define your site root and lib path for a reason; maybe you need to use them when you want to include your files?

Comment: that should be like this ? 
            defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define ('SITE_ROOT', 
            $_SERVER['C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-
            14.1VC9\data\localweb'].DS.'studentTrans');

Comment: @belhadjabdou if paths defined correctly, must be like this require_once LIB_PATH."config.php";

Comment: @Оzgur You can use both \ and / on Windows.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac thanks for that. It is weird but good to know 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the relative position of the file you are trying to include, to the file you execute.

However you can get the path using only **DIR** and then navigate through it.

For example,

```
$this_directory = __DIR__;
$file_to_include = $this_directory."\includes\config.php";
require_once $file_to_include;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why would you put `__DIR__` to a variable?

Comment: i fix the problem thank i juste change the folder to 'studentTrans'    AND PUT ROOT OF EASYPHP  THANK YOU ANY WAY

Comment: @NinoŠkopac it is to make it clear, I better comment it

Comment: If you assign a constant to a variable, you're losing immutability, the very essence of a constant. Also, backslashes are only going to work on Windows, whereas forward slashes will work everywhere. Just do `require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/config.php'`

Comment: @NinoŠkopac Nino , I know how to write it and I should write it in a single line  I am trying to make him understand...

Answer (score -1):

you have something wrong in the file "initialize.php" included ..

Answer (score -1):

the problem fixed it's was here !! 
 defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define ('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer- 14.1VC9\data\localweb'].DS.'studentTrans');